# Experiencing different CSS results on different sites?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align a span-tag inside a DIV. I have a working example on JSFiddle but the EXACT same CSS and HTML will not work on my own site.

```css
#drop_zone {
    width: 500px;
    outline: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}

#drop_zone span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 19px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone"><span>Drag file here.<br />Your file will <strong>not</strong> be uploaded!</span></div>
```

Now, it works on JSFiddle and on Stackoverflow, but why does it not work on my own site? You can check out the results here: http://snorlax.org/stackoverflow.html

If you check the source code, you can see it's the exact same code. What on earh is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document is missing the Doctype, so you are triggering [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode). The feature you are trying to use only works correctly in Standards mode. Add a Doctype. Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: Man, the simpliest things always gets to me. God damnit. I never declare the doctype when I'm just fooling around. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: You don't have to. But better stop the bad habit and always add the doctype :). And if that really solved the problem: mark the answer as the correct one.